# A library to get position with accelerometer gyro and magneto

Tags: python, position, accelerometer

I'm using a sensor which is a accelerometer+gyro+magneto (all in one chip). I was wondering if anyone knows a library which can help me get the position from those values.

I mean starting with a 0.0 (lat/long) and updating values. If there are no library, I'm still seeking links to get clues on how to do the maths. I've seen posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821105/accelerometer-gyro-and-magnetometer) one or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068197/how-to-determine-relative-position-using-accelerometer-and-gyro-data) one but I didn't find what I was looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it can help anyone, I've found the exact topic I was looking for. Here it is :

https://lb.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=127930

[EDITED]

Here's the idea :

[image]

**Algorithm 2** :

I have found two method, I do not know which one could be better,

```
Accroll = atan2( accy / (accy^2 + accz^2) )
Accpitch = atan2( accx / (accx^2 + accz^2) )
```

source: http://franciscoraulortega.com/pubs/Algo3DFusionsMems.pdf

```
Accroll = atan2(accy, accz) 
Accpitch = atan2( -accx, sqrt(accy^2 + accz^2) )
```

source: [https://www.nxp.com/files-tatic/sensors/doc/app_note/AN3461.pdf](https://www.nxp.com/files-static/sensors/doc/app_note/AN3461.pdf)
page 10

**Algorithm 3**

I think it should be a complementary filter like this maybe:

Calculate pitch and roll with gyroscope data:

```
Gyrpitch = gyrox * dt;
Gyrroll = gyroy * dt;
```

Calculate pitch and roll after the filter:

```
pitch = Gyrpitch * 0.98 + Accpitch * 0.02;
roll = Gyrroll * 0.98 + Accroll * 0.02;
```

**Algorithm 1**

```
XH = mx cos(pitch) + my sin(pitch) sin(roll) + mz sin(pitch) cos(roll)
YH = my cos(roll) + mz sin(roll) 
yaw = atan2(−YH / XH)
```

where: m: magnetometer data
source: http://franciscoraulortega.com/pubs/Algo3DFusionsMems.pdf